# Questions on to use Node.js as local server with Braintree?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, braintree

I'm not new to JavaScript but I *am* new to Node.js and back end languages. I have a very simple question.

I've installed and setup Node.js on my computer and I'm attempting to get a server going between my static files & directory(s) and my browser to be able to send and receive requests. I've downloaded Braintree's free Sandbox (found [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox)) for practice to get some faux transactions going just to gain a better understanding of how this can work.

I set up a local server by running `npm install -g http-server` on my command line and then `http-server` to set it up.

I then received the following message in my command line:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./public
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://10.0.1.4:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

So, with this setup...if I wanted to do `get()` and `post()` methods and see it rendered and communicating between my "server" and my static files. How do I do this? For example, if I were to set up Braintree's sandboxed environment and then create a clientToken using the following code from Braintree's website

```
const http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express'),
    braintree = require('braintree');


const gateway = braintree.connect({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "xxxxx", 
  publicKey: "xxxxx", 
  privateKey: "xxxxx" //blocked out real numbers for privacy
});
```

Here is the remaining code I hae to create a "client Token" for a transaction...and [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/node) is the guide I'm following via Braintree's website...

```
http.createServer((req,res) => {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({
  },(err, response) => {
    if(err){
      throw new Error(err);
    }
    if(response.success){
      var clientToken = response.clientToken 
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
      res.write(clientToken);
      res.end("<p>This is the end</p>");
    } else {
      res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.end('Whoops! Something went wrong.');
    }
  });
}).listen(8080,'127.0.0.1');
```

So, my question is...if I wanted to generate send a token to a client using the `get()` method...how would I do that? Would it have to be a separate js file? How would they be linked? If they're in the same directory will they just see each other?

Here is an example on Braintree's website of how a client token may be sent:

```
app.get("/client_token", function (req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    res.send(response.clientToken);
  });
});
```

How could this be integrated into my current code and actually work? I apologize if these are elementary questions, but I would like to gain a better understanding of this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about braintree, but usually you would use somthing like express.js to handel stuff like this. So I'll give you some quick examples from an app I have.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var http = require('http');
var app = require('../server.js');
var models = require("../models");

models.sync(function () {
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(4242, function(){
        console.log(4242);
    });
});
```

So that's the file that gets everything started.  Don't worry about models, its just syncing the db.

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
// share public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./router.js')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

next up is the server.js that ties eveything together.  app.use() lines are for adding middleware and the app.use(logger('dev')); sets the route logger for what your looking for.

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); shares out all files in the public directory and is what your looking for for static files

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(app){
    //catch
 app.get('*', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

last piece is the router.js.  This is were you would put all of you get and post routes.  generally I've found that if you see app.get or app.post in examples there talking about express stuff.  It's used a lot with node and just makes routing way easier.

Also if your using tokens a route would look like this.

```js
app.get('/print', checkToken, function(req, res){
  print.getPrinters(function(err, result){
    response(err, result, req, res);
  });
});

function checkToken(req, res, next){
  models.Tokens.findOne({value: req.headers.token}, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }else if(result == null){
      console.log(req.headers);
      res.status(401).send('unauthorized');
    }else{
      next();
    }
  });
}
```

so any route you want to make sure had a token you would just pass that function into it.  again models is for db